# Google Analytics script conflict - not tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, ssl, google-analytics

Site: https://nordicecommercesummit.se/malmo/

This is my last ditch effort to fix GA on our site. We've had it running for the better part of 2 years now without incident. Over the summer though we added a few new pages and redesigned some things, that's when I noticed that it had stopped tracking. The site is WordPress with Cloudfare SSL. SSL was added around the same time as the redesign. Only one jQuery plugin was added, however, this is on our other sites without any issues.

I'm stumped, and I've tried seemingly everything. Here's the list per Google's advice:

- Re-add tracking js
- Moved tracking code(originally in the footer, but moved around to
  head and body)
- Changed target url to https (I suspected our switch to https could be the problem, Cloudfare)
- Removed any possible conflicts
- Used GA Debugger

All of this was to no avail. Says it's still not installed. Google said they see that it's not tracking but confirm it should be working. They advised that it was on my end, or WordPress.

So I was hoping someone might be able to lead me down the right road to fix this irritating issue. I'm a front end dev, so I only dabble in JS when needed. So I presume it could be a script conflict, but it just doesn't that way. But since my knowledge of JS is limited, I'd love a little input.

Comment: According to the GA debugger the tracking runs fine, so if no data shows up  this does not seem to be code-related. Check if you are using the correct Account ID and that there are no wrongly configured filters in your admin section that throw out all data. This is certainly not a wordpress problem - I can see the http request going out, so the problem is at the receiving end.

Comment: The ID appears to be right. Especially since I've pasted it in there multiple times directly from the GA Admin. The only filter I've added is one to include our hostname. However, not sure it was necessary so I removed it just now in case. Otherwise I literally cannot see anything else that could be leaving out data. I do get hits, but it's only 0, 1, or 4-5 every few days.

Comment: You know what, I think it might be working. After removing the filter, I am starting to see real time traffic from Stackoverflow. I think I was filtering all traffic except from our site. Not sure how that decision was made. Probably idiotically :)

Comment: Always have an unfiltered view - that really helps with the debugging, plus you have a backup for all data that's been destroyed by wrong filters. In fact I usually have at least three views, one for raw data, one for testing and one for the daily work (btw. if you have tested a filter successfully in the "test view" then recreate it for the live view - do not use the "apply the existing filter" option, else the filter in the live view will change, too, if you make changes in the test view.

Comment: Great advice Eike! I will get it all setup now. I don't want this disaster to happen again.